# php fgets function stuck the server

Tags: php

I have function `build_additional_docs` which calls another function that do few actions, but first it's call to function `read_all_file`, which extract the file to string variable and return it.

It's worked perfect when the function `create_file_node` has been called from another function.

but when it's called from `build_additional_docs`, the client wait to server untill time out...
I think that the function fail on `fgets()`.

**Additional comment:** When I call function `create_file_node` whith with the same files, and the different is that file name is static string, and I have no foreach loop, the code works again...

here is my code:

```
function build_additional_docs($dir_name, $addDocsArr){
foreach ($addDocsArr as $doc) {
    if($summery != ''){
        $fileName = $dir_name . '\\' . $doc;
        create_file_node($fileName);
    }
}


    function create_file_node($fileName){    global $base_url;
try{
        $text = read_all_file($fileName);
}
catch (Exception $ex){
     // some message here
}
return 0;
}

 function read_all_file($file_name){
$file_handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line[] = fgets($file_handle);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return implode('',$line);
}
```

Comment: use set_time_limit(0) to increase execution

Comment: If you have so many files that the php timelimit is not sufficient (it cannot always be increased with `set_time_limit()`) you can build an array with the paths to the files you want to scan, write it into a session variable and do it one by one. Every 30 seconds or so (depending on the timelimit) you can redirect to the same page and do the next batch of files from the session variable. This way you can even show a progress bar of sorts and the user knows something is happening while he waits.

Comment: btw, your function `read_all_file()` seems like a re implementation of the php function `file_get_contents`

Comment: I don't think that it's had anything to do with time limit. When I call create_file_node with tow calls out of foreach loop, the operation succeed. But when I call to create_file_node from foreach loop, with the very same files, the operation fails... It's only tow files. One almost empty, and one has some content. I even tried with other files, it didn't worked....

Comment: And when I call to create_node_file() from another function, with much bigger files, and about 49 files with nested folder, with while loop, And even with some requrse, the operation succeed...

Comment: I think I know what is the problem... somehow a character like breakline or end of line is within the file name, therefore, the file won't open... but I gets the string from user, and I would like to know how to clean the file name... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake!
$addDocsArr variable is return value from explode() function for split string to seperated files names. The returned array include strings of file name with **spacial characters** that cannot be seen... 
so when i add the code: 
`$fileName = $dir_name . '\\' . substr($doc, 0,strlen($doc) - 1);`

the code worked.